# different colors within a table in c

Tags: c, arrays, colors

I'm doing a school project where we need to code a board game (Medina). Its going well but im having some trouble.

There are 4 different color palace pieces (shown as a 'P' on the game board) that need to appear in an array. Displaying colors in the console application isnt a problem except when in the array

The array needs to be entirely white but the program needs to differentiate which 'P' needs to be which color.

Here is my switch case for the player choice (only the palace pieces):

```
switch(c)
{
case 1:
    printf("What color? 1 - red, 2 - grey, 3 - black, 4 - brown\n");
    scanf ("%d", &d);
    switch(d)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Where would you like to place your palace? X Y\n");
            scanf ("%d %d",&y, &x);
            tab[x-1][y-1]='P';
            player[t].po--;
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Where would you like to place your palace? X Y\n");
            scanf ("%d %d",&y, &x);
            tab[x-1][y-1]='P';
            player[t].pg--;
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Where would you like to place your palace? X Y\n");
            scanf ("%d %d",&y, &x);
            tab[x-1][y-1]='P';
            player[t].pn--;
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Where would you like to place your palace? X Y\n");
            scanf ("%d %d",&y, &x);
            tab[x-1][y-1]='P';
            player[t].pb--;
            break;
    }
    break;
```

this is my display:

```
void display(char tab[DIMH][DIMV])
{
int i, j, k;


for(i=0; i<9; i++)
{
    printf("  %d ", i+1);
}
for(i=0; i<9; i++)
{
    printf(" %d ", i+10);
}
printf(" \n");
for(i=0; i<DIMV; i++)
{
    printf("+---");
}
printf("+\n");
for(i=0; i<DIMH; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<DIMV; j++)
    {
        printf("| %c ", tab[i][j]);
    }
    printf("| %d \n", i+1);

    for(k=0; k<DIMV; k++)
    {
        printf("+---");
    }
    printf("+\n");
}

}
```

I have a struct player outlining the number of pieces each player has (player.pb is a players black palaces for example).

Alternatively, if anyone knows how to display multiple letters in the table (Pb = black palace etc.) while keeping the correct spacing on the board it would be very helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The colors question is specific to your hardware and software environment. If you know you're outputting to an ANSI terminal, you can use escape codes, but using a curses library like ncurses is probably your best bet on UNIX-like operating systems. On Windows, many command line compilers have libraries for that sort of thing. Check your documentation.

For printing multiple characters, you'll need to change to printing strings. You can use a field width specifier to help, or make all your strings the same length (e.g. two characters long).